# Best json rpc 2.0 library for Android

Tags: java, android, json, json-rpc

I have json rpc 2.0 server written in php. Currently I'm looking for a library that allows auto generation json rpc requests instead of using manual serialization.

I found a bunch of different libraries and really don't know which is more convenient. Did anybody successfully use one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best library json I've ever found is [JSON-RPC 2.0](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html)

For making requests you will need [base](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html) part of library. But if you want automatically handle server resonces you can take a look at [client](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-client.html) library. There are pretty much easy to understand tutorials. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Seems this lib's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[android-json-rpc](https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/) is a pretty simple library.
Here is the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/wiki/Documentation).

Comment: Yeah, thx, I saw it, but docs aren't very detailed

Comment: Uses old org.apache.http library which can be bypassed by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/50779232/5956589